Unable to access BIOS to disable Secure Boot
I have an old school laptop that I want to use to play around with different Linux distros.
It came with Windows 10, and a couple months ago I installed Ubuntu Server on it to host NextCloud. I am trying to install NixOS on it now, but cannot get past Secure Boot. If I try to boot into the USB from the boot menu, it gives me an error stating that Secure Boot is enabled and I cannot proceed (seen here). I cannot access the BIOS for whatever reason.
I don't know the exact key for the BIOS for this device as it is a bit obscure, but I tried sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup but it just boots to a blank screen (screen is on, just nothing being displayed).
I do not know what else to do, and am starting to believe that this device will just permanently have Ubuntu on it. I cannot for the life of me remember how I managed to install Ubuntu on this device.
Can someone please help me either figure out and fix the issue of not being able to access the BIOS (since it is just a blank screen) or pose another solution to installing another OS on it despite Secure Boot being enabled.
Here is a link for some specs of the device.

Any OEM device that came with Windows 10 is required to allow Secure Boot to be disabled. Only tablets are excluded from that requirement. That device is a tablet not a laptop.

With that obvious observation out of the way, the option likely is there, it’s probably just named “secure boot” ASUS is notorious for doing that as an example

The issue is not that I cannot find secure boot or simply cannot disable it, I cannot access the BIOS. It simply shows a blank screen

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

@jsotola I have revised the question, but basically all I want is to be able to install NixOS (or any other OS) but Secure Boot is in the way and I cannot disable it because for some odd reason the BIOS setup won't show and I'm trying to find a solution

What is the exact text displayed for it gives me an error stating that Secure Boot is enabled and I cannot proceed?

@ChesterGillon This shows the same thing I am seeing

@CodePidgy this site is not a forum... important information does not belong in a comment ... please update the question instead

Apologies, still new to this stuff. Revised the question

@DrMoishePippik That is the most helpful comment I've gotten so far. I'm happy to make due with only using an OS that can support Secure Boot if that's what I must do. Will you make your response an answer so I can mark this as answered?

@CodePidgy, done -- it's an answer.

@CodePidgy ummm several suggestions:

From Windows - you could press SHIFT while pressing Restart from the start menu, to boot into BIOS ( in the blue screen go to "advanced", then "UEFI options" ) . Just to make sure there is one, at all. I understand you've already removed Win10, but this is still an option, if youv'e got the time to reinstall it.

IM GUESSING this should also work from Linux, but f*ck me, Ubuntu 24 LTS was a huge pain in the butt... They might've changed that too? This did seem to work, as of 2022 -- "sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup"

@Netan I actually just tried this like 5 minutes ago also wondering the same thing as a last ditch attempt, it doesn't work, unfortunately

Rather than describing it as "an old school laptop", be specific: "Curro Golden Creek 360" 2-in-1 device. For that device, my search online found no user access to BIOS.
Frankly, I'd be happy that it runs Ubuntu!
If you don't like Ubuntu Server, try the Desktop version... or try another OS that works on Secure Boot, such as the most recent versions of the following distros:

CentOS
Debian
Fedora
OpenSUSE
Red Hat Enterprise Linux

BTW, specs on that tablet are not terrible:  Celeron N3010 CPU, 256 GB SSD, 4 GB RAM. Though I'm surprised it can run Windows 10, Linux should be much faster and require much less SSD space. On an old Acer, Ubuntu Desktop runs with just 2 GB RAM and using about 14 GB drive space for the OS, LibreOffice suite, Firefox, Thunderbird, Calibre and various Windows applications running under wine: IrfanView, 7-Zip, Sumatra PDF Viewer and PDF-XChange Editor, etc.

The specs aren't the worst, it just sucks for Windows. This is why I wanted to use it as a little test platform for distros I'm interested in

One issue from the question:

I am trying to install NixOS on it now, but cannot get past Secure Boot.

I'm not a user of NixOS but checking the NixOS Secure Boot wiki page it says:

On NixOS, Secure Boot can be enabled via the project Lanzaboote.
Warning: Lanzaboote is still in development and requires some prerequisites and precautions. Currently it's only available for nixos-unstable. For more information, please see the GitHub repository or the Quick Start guide.

The Quick Start: NixOS Secure Boot shows that the installation must start with secure boot disabled. Only after NixOS is configured is secure boot enabled.
Therefore, with a PC in which you can't enter the BIOS to disable secure boot, then it looks like NixOS isn't currently a viable distribution.
To add to the distributions in the answer, I have been able to install AlmaLinux 8.10 and AlmaLinux 9.4 on HP PCs in which secure boot is enabled, without needing to temporarily disable secure boot during the installation.
